# accessing properties of nested objects with Lodash

Tags: json, lodash

Lodash's [documentation for `map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) contains an example like this:

```
var users = [{'user': 'barney'}, {'user': 'fred'}];
_.map(users, 'user'); // => ['barney', 'fred']
```

I have data similar to that, but nested.  Theirs is an array of objects, but I have an array of objects, each of which contains an array of objects, too.  Expanding on the Lodash example, my data is like this:

```
var users = [
  {'mapping': [{'user': 'barney'}, {'user': 'fred'}]},
  {'mapping': [{'user': 'sherlock'}, {'user': 'watson'}]},
];
```

I'd like to get back all four of those names.  (An array of arrays is acceptable.)

I tried a number of ways to do this.  You can see my attempts at: https://runkit.com/lsloan0000/lodash-map-nested

Eventually, I found this solution:

```
// I didn't think it would take this much code
_.map(users, function (value, key, collection) {
    return _.map(value.mapping, 'user');
});
```

I thought Lodash has so many features that I wouldn't need to use a callback function.

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

I know I can probably skip the `key` and `collection` arguments.  Eventually, I plan to have this code return the *objects* whose `mapping` contains two specific names.  (All objects with mappings for "fred" and "barney" together.)  So I've left those arguments there, because I think I will need them for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMap) to flatten the nested array into a single array, and then map it to `user` values:

```js
var users = [
  {'mapping': [{'user': 'barney'}, {'user': 'fred'}]},
  {'mapping': [{'user': 'sherlock'}, {'user': 'watson'}]},
];

var result = _(users)
  .flatMap('mapping')
  .map('user')
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And without a lodash chain:

```js
var users = [
  {'mapping': [{'user': 'barney'}, {'user': 'fred'}]},
  {'mapping': [{'user': 'sherlock'}, {'user': 'watson'}]},
];

var result = _.map(_.flatMap(users, 'mapping'), 'user');
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'll check out `flatMap()`.  I think this solution won't fit with my stated goal of returning the objects whose `mapping` contains specific values, though.  Maybe instead of posting a question about this specific step of my process, I should post one about the complete process (getting mappings, find those that match criteria, and return the objects that contain them).

Comment: You can achieve that easily by replacing the `.map('user')` with a filter, and a predicate you want the object to match. The result will be an array of objects.

Comment: OK.  Can you explain why you used chaining in your solution.  I'd read that chaining in Lodash isn't a great idea because the program is virtually forced to load the full version of Lodash.  Supposedly, using chaining a Lodash subset works, but the loading of other modules with Lodash functions is problematic.

Comment: The problem with chaining is that you can't load lodash in a modular way (ie just the parts you need). I've used it in this case, because it's easier to understand then a method inside a method (see 2nd example).